# Nodes are not connecting in compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, error

Im using blender 3 .
after my render is finished, i was trying to do some post processing in the compositing tab.
but the nodes were not connecting to each other.
please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  The Community Bot's right, more details could be helpful, or a screenshot showing your whole compositor workspace.  Also, it's often a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem.  The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Possible solution : https://blenderartists.org/t/2-8-cant-connect-compositor-nodes/1188364/4 https://developer.blender.org/T74355